# Flipbook Image Placement within Komaclass scrbook

Tags: koma-script, marginpar, animations, scrlayer-scrpage

I want to add to my document (`scrbook`) a flipbook in the top right or lower right margin. I've already managed to insert the pictures on all pages with an increasing number in the filename. Just to mention: Komaclasses complain about `fancyhdr` which is the reason I do not want to use it. The same applies to the package `flipbook` which loads `fancyhdr` itself.

I struggle with the proper placement. Consider following MWE and have a look at the compiled result:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\makeatletter
\rohead*{%
  \if@mainmatter
  \begin{picture}(-\marginparsep,\headheight)
    \put(0,-\headsep){\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth,height=37.4pt]{example-image-a}}
  \end{picture}
  \else\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{title}
\begin{description}
  \item[headheight] \the\headheight 
  \item[headsep] \the\headsep 
  \item[marginparwidth] \the\marginparwidth 
  \item[marginparsep] \the\marginparsep 
\end{description}

\paragraph{Intended size and placement of flipbook image:}
\begin{itemize}
  \item width of image = marginparwidth
  \item height of image = headsep + headheight
  \item lower left corner of image should be at the top left corner of the margin notes
    box (compare showframe)
  \item Alternative placement: top left corner of image should be at the lower
    left corner of the margin notes box
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My remaining issue how to place the image without iterating the values for the picture environment and the put command. And as bonus how can I avoid the `Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: \headheight too low`.

Comment: Do you want the flipbook only on odd pages, or on all pages in the appropriately mirrored configuration?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I guess that would be an additional feature which I hadn't yet in mind :-). So I stick to only odd pages for now. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would declare an own layer for the flipbook which can be added to the page styles `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings`. Then you can still use `\ohead` and `\rohead` for other contents.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{picture}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\makeatletter
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  oddpage,
  textarea,
  addhoffset=\textwidth+\marginparsep,
  width=\marginparwidth,
  height=\headsep+\headheight,
  align=b,
  mode=picture,
  contents={%
    \if@mainmatter
      \putLL{\includegraphics[width=\layerwidth,height=\layerheight]{example-image-a}}%
    \fi
  }
]{flipbook.odd}
\makeatother

\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{flipbook.odd}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{flipbook.odd}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{title}
\begin{description}
  \item[headheight] \the\headheight 
  \item[headsep] \the\headsep 
  \item[marginparwidth] \the\marginparwidth 
  \item[marginparsep] \the\marginparsep 
\end{description}

\paragraph{Intended size and placement of flipbook image:}
\begin{itemize}
  \item width of image = marginparwidth
  \item height of image = headsep + headheight
  \item lower left corner of image should be at the top left corner of the margin notes
    box (compare showframe)
  \item Alternative placement: top right corner of image should be at the lower
    left corner of the margin notes box
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]